# Send data from ESP32 to Firebase Realtime Database BUT using Firebase emulators (locally)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have an ESP32 sending sensor data via WiFi to a Firebase Realtime Database (live) — all working fine. However I want to use the Firebase emulators to develop the program solely on my local network rather than to keep sending data over the internet, and potentially incurring data charges on my Firebase account (I'm sometimes sending thousands of writes per minute).

The part of the code in the ESP32 file (.cpp) I think I need to change is:

```
#define DATABASE_URL "https://xxxx-xxxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/"
#define API_KEY "123456789012345678901234567890"
```

I've got the firebase database running on my local network (192.168.0.10:9000), so I can see that it's all up and running correctly. I can even write data to it with some simple HTML/Javascript code. I just can't get the ESP32 to send anything to it. I've tried the following URLs:

```
#define DATABASE_URL "http://192.168.0.10:9000/?ns=xxxx-xxxxxxxx-66rc4/"
#define DATABASE_URL "http://192.168.0.10:9000/?ns=xxxx-xxxxxxxx-66rc4/data"
#define DATABASE_URL "http://192.168.0.10:9000/database/xxxx-xxxxxxxx-66rc4/"
#define DATABASE_URL "http://192.168.0.10:9000/database/xxxx-xxxxxxxx-66rc4/data"
```

I just get an error in the serial monitor which reads: `[285954][E][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1582] hostByName(): DNS Failed for 192.168.0.10:9000`

I'm using [this FirebaseESP32 library](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP32) for reference.

Am I missing something obvious? I just can't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL parser is a bit simple and doesn't support the port number. It doesn't seem like the library has an interface for changing the port either. Try running your test service on the default port and removing it from the definition of DATABASE_URL:

```
//#define DATABASE_URL "http://192.168.0.10:9000/?ns=xxxx-xxxxxxxx-66rc4/"
#define DATABASE_URL "http://192.168.0.10/?ns=xxxx-xxxxxxxx-66rc4/"
```

Comment: I tried various different ports, including the default, but all gave the same error unfortunately

Comment: I'm suggesting that you omit the port number from your URL definition. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: I ran the databse emulator on port 80 (default for localhost) which allowed me to access the database URL in a browser without a port number — great! But the ESP32 now gives a different error and therefore still won't connect. The error is `[ 33418][E][WiFiClientImpl.h:347] tcpConnect(): connect on fd 48, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer"`.

Comment: Double-check the firewall settings on the host running Firebase emulator, try to connect to it from another device in the same network. If that doesn't work, then perhaps you should share a minimal reproducible example of your ESP code.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Data can be written with HTML/Javascript code but can't get the ESP32 to send anything to it.